# MVC second login screen

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, dotnetnuke, adfs

I have a DotNetNuke MVC website where users login through ADFS, after logging in they enter the members section.

A part of the member area contains personal data and I want to add a additional login-form (again against the ADFS service) where the users should authenticate themselves again for extra security reasons, with a session timeout.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - once you are logged in that's it.

For additional security, I suggest you add MFA.

Or add [custom authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-build-custom-auth-method).